# I can't use a group name like this "abc_def" using Patterns

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem with a series of patterns that have to be compiled. Here is an example:

```
...(?<NOT>\bNOT\b)|(?<LEFT_PAR>\()|(?<RIGHT_PAR>\))...
```

These group names "LEFT_PAR" and "RIGHT_PAR" raise an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: 
named capturing group is missing trailing '>'
```

I'm pretty sure that the underscore is the problem. Searching online I didn't find anything helpful and I can't understand why this _ is causing me this issue when i saw examples in python working great. I've read that it is treated like a normal char in Java Patterns. Obviously, if I delete it, it works great.

Can you help me, please? :)
Thanks.

EDIT:

```
 public enum Patterns(){
   NOT("\\bNOT\\b"),
   LEFT-PAR("\\("), 
   RIGHT-PAR("\\)"); [...] 
 }
 //i'm cutting enum constructor and toString() method...

//That's the part of the method that uses enum

StringBuilder allPatterns = new StringBuilder();

//This loop creates a unique group of patterns (key-value)
for (validTokens t : validTokens.values()) 
    allPatterns.append("|(?<" + t.name() + ">" + t + ")");

//Compile all Patterns and create a group
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(allPatterns.toString().substring(1)); //ERROR
```

I can't change any of the names because of project's specifics. The method and the enum worked well until now... This _ ruined all xD If you can help me to figure out, please.
Thanks.

Comment: Since you are sure underscores are the problem, does it work if using "LEFTPAR"/"RIGHTPAR" as names? If that is the case, then consider using "leftPar"/"rightPar" (i.e. use case to signify word breaks) and moving on with code.

Comment: Post an example of string you want use the regex on and probably even the entire regex.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't use other names 'cause it's a project with well-defined specifics :/ At the moment these names and their relative patterns, are controlled by an enum. Ex: 
        NOT("\\bNOT\\b"),
 LEFT_PAR("\\("), //LEFT-PAR
 RIGHT_PAR("\\)"), //RIGHT-PAR

Comment: @LeGent001 What about creating an identifier transformation function (or maintaining a separate map)?

Comment: @user2864740 For example?
Maybe i've understood your idea... and, perhaps, it's the unic way :/

Comment: @LeGent001 Transform the pattern names LEFT_PAR to LeftPar (such that it is a reversible mapping) - the Java code will use "LeftPar" to deal with the capture groups but will read and consume "LEFT_PAR". If there isn't a trivially transformable mapping then a Map can be used to remember the source identifiers.

Comment: Yeah.. maybe it's the only way.
Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> A capturing group can also be assigned a "name", a named-capturing
>   group, and then be back-referenced later by the "name". Group names
>   are composed of the following characters. The first character must be
>   a letter.
>
> - The uppercase letters 'A' through 'Z' ('\u0041' through '\u005a'),
> - The lowercase letters 'a' through 'z' ('\u0061' through '\u007a'),
> - The digits '0' through '9' ('\u0030' through '\u0039'),

Underscores are forbidden. Remember that different languages have different regex dialects; what works in Python may not work in Java, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, you're correct - underscores aren't allowed.  From [a published copy of the relevant code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.java.html):

```
  778                           if (ASCII.isLower(nextChar) ||
  779                               ASCII.isUpper(nextChar) ||
  780                               ASCII.isDigit(nextChar)) {
  781                               gsb.append(nextChar);
  782                               cursor++;
```