# Modifing PCRE Regex to C# or Java Supported Regex

Tags: java, regex

**Business requirement:**
Address needs to parsed to Street, House number and Address line 2

**Example single line addresses**

```
Bygholm Søpark 21B, 
Peder Skrams Gade 9  3. tv., 
Willemoesgade 29  kid.
```

The below PCRE regular expressing is working for the above business scenario. I need to use this regular expression and create a Java method which accepts an input parameter (Single line address) and returns the output from Regex groups (Street, House number and Address line 2). Could anyone help me with this?

**Regex:**

```
/
\A\s*
(?: #########################################################################
    # Option A: [<Addition to address 1>] <House number> <Street name>      #
    # [<Addition to address 2>]                                             #
    #########################################################################
    (?:(?P<A_Addition_to_address_1>.*?),\s*)? # Addition to address 1
(?:No\.\s*)?
    (?P<A_House_number_1>\pN+[a-zA-Z]?(?:\s*[-\/\pP]\s*\pN+[a-zA-Z]?)*) # House number
\s*,?\s*
    (?P<A_Street_name_1>(?:[a-zA-Z]\s*|\pN\pL{2,}\s\pL)\S[^,#]*?(?<!\s)) # Street name
\s*(?:(?:[,\/]|(?=\#))\s*(?!\s*No\.)
    (?P<A_Addition_to_address_2>(?!\s).*?))? # Addition to address 2
|   #########################################################################
    # Option B: [<Addition to address 1>] <Street name> <House number>      #
    # [<Addition to address 2>]                                             #
    #########################################################################
    (?:(?P<B_Addition_to_address_1>.*?),\s*(?=.*[,\/]))? # Addition to address 1
    (?!\s*No\.)(?P<B_Street_name>\S\s*\S(?:[^,#](?!\b\pN+\s))*?(?<!\s)) # Street name
\s*[\/,]?\s*(?:\sNo\.)?\s+
    (?P<B_House_number>\pN+\s*-?[a-zA-Z]?(?:\s*[-\/\pP]?\s*\pN+(?:\s*[\-a-zA-Z])?)*|[IVXLCDM]+(?!.*\b\pN+\b))(?<!\s) # House number
\s*(?:(?:[,\/]|(?=\#)|\s)\s*(?!\s*No\.)\s*
    (?P<B_Addition_to_address_2>(?!\s).*?))? # Addition to address 2
)
\s*\Z
```

https://regex101.com/library/lU7gY7

**JAVA Method:**

```
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class regEx {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
          // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
          String line = "Bygholm Søpark 21B";
          String pattern = "\\A\\s*\r\n" + 
                "(?: #########################################################################\r\n" + 
                "    # Option A: [<Addition to address 1>] <House number> <Street name>      #\r\n" + 
                "    # [<Addition to address 2>]                                             #\r\n" + 
                "    #########################################################################\r\n" + 
                "    (?:(?:P<A_Addition_to_address_1>.*?),\\s*)? # Addition to address 1\r\n" + 
                "(?:No\\.\\s*)?\r\n" + 
                "    (?:P<A_House_number_1>\\pN+[a-zA-Z]?(?:\\s*[-\\/\\pP]\\s*\\pN+[a-zA-Z]?)*) # House number\r\n" + 
                "\\s*,?\\s*\r\n" + 
                "    (?:P<A_Street_name_1>(?:[a-zA-Z]\\s*|\\pN\\pL{2,}\\s\\pL)\\S[^,#]*?(?<!\\s)) # Street name\r\n" + 
                "\\s*(?:(?:[,\\/]|(?=\\#))\\s*(?!\\s*No\\.)\r\n" + 
                "    (?:P<A_Addition_to_address_2>(?!\\s).*?))? # Addition to address 2\r\n" + 
                "|   #########################################################################\r\n" + 
                "    # Option B: [<Addition to address 1>] <Street name> <House number>      #\r\n" + 
                "    # [<Addition to address 2>]                                             #\r\n" + 
                "    #########################################################################\r\n" + 
                "    (?:(?:P<B_Addition_to_address_1>.*?),\\s*(?=.*[,\\/]))? # Addition to address 1\r\n" + 
                "    (?:!\\s*No\\.)(?:P<B_Street_name>\\S\\s*\\S(?:[^,#](?!\\b\\pN+\\s))*?(?:<!\\s)) # Street name\r\n" + 
                "\\s*[\\/,]?\\s*(?:\\sNo\\.)?\\s+\r\n" + 
                "    (?:P<B_House_number>\\pN+\\s*-?[a-zA-Z]?(?:\\s*[-\\/\\pP]?\\s*\\pN+(?:\\s*[\\-a-zA-Z])?)*|[IVXLCDM]+(?!.*\\b\\pN+\\b))(?<!\\s) # House number\r\n" + 
                "\\s*(?:(?:[,\\/]|(?=\\#)|\\s)\\s*(?!\\s*No\\.)\\s*\r\n" + 
                "    (?:P<B_Addition_to_address_2>(?!\\s).*?))? # Addition to address 2\r\n" + 
                ")\r\n" + 
                "\\s*\\Z";

          // Create a Pattern object
          Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

          // Now create a matcher object.
          Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
          if (m.find( )) {
             System.out.println("B_Street_name: " + m.group(1) );
             System.out.println("B_House_number: " + m.group(2) );
             System.out.println("B_Addition_to_address_2: " + m.group(3) );
          }else {
             System.out.println("NO MATCH");
          }
       }
}
```

Comment: It is basiclly the same. Replace all `(?P<` with `(?<` and `\pX` with `\p{X}`. Place the regex string in a verbatim string literal. Use `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` option.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor for the response. I will check and get back to you.

Comment: Please add what you managed to get to in the question body if it still does not work

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I have modified the question and explained my requirement. I created the Java method by using the above-mentioned Regex. I am a beginner to both Regex and programming.  Since I am getting compilation errors I have replaced the '(?' with '(?:' based on some suggestions from some blog. However, it is not giving the expected result when I pass the Address string. It is giving the result as 'NO MATCH'.

Comment: Ok, so do you need to make the regex  work  in Java or C#? Their free spacing modes differ

Comment: It needs to be work in Java and I put the Java method in the question.

Comment: That is important. I will come back in a few minutes with a solution.

Comment: Answer [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56055549/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of things to bear in mind.

- *Named capturing groups*: There syntax in Java is `(?<name>pattern)` and the names can only consist of ASCII digits or letters (see [I can't use a group name like this "abc_def" using Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21271972/3832970)). Replace all `(?P<name_parts>...)` with `(?<nameparts>...)`
- *Use of `#`*: In many flavors but Java, the free-spacing mode allows using a literal `#` inside character classes unescaped. In Java, any meaningful whitespace and `#` MUST be escaped EVEN inside character classes (replace all `#` with `\\#` inside character classes and pattern).
- `Pattern.COMMENTS` is used in Java to enable free-spacing / comment mode. Alternatively, add `(?x)` at the pattern start.

Here is your code fix:

```
String line = "Bygholm Søpark 21B";
String pattern = "\\A\\s*\r\n" + 
  "(?: #########################################################################\r\n" + 
  "    # Option A: [<Addition to address 1>] <House number> <Street name>      #\r\n" + 
  "    # [<Addition to address 2>]                                             #\r\n" + 
  "    #########################################################################\r\n" + 
  "    (?:(?<AAdditiontoaddress1>.*?),\\s*)?         # Addition to address 1\r\n" + 
  "(?:No\\.\\s*)?\r\n" + 
  "    (?<AHousenumber1>\\pN+[a-zA-Z]?(?:\\s*[-/\\pP]\\s*\\pN+[a-zA-Z]?)*) # House number\r\n" + 
  "\\s*,?\\s*\r\n" + 
  "    (?<AStreetname1>(?:[a-zA-Z]\\s*|\\pN\\pL{2,}\\s\\pL)\\S[^,\\#]*?(?<!\\s)) # Street name\r\n" + 
  "\\s*(?:(?:[,/]|(?=\\#))\\s*(?!\\s*No\\.)\r\n" + 
  "    (?<AAdditiontoaddress2>(?!\\s).*?))?              # Addition to address 2\r\n" + 
  "|   #########################################################################\r\n" + 
  "    # Option B: [<Addition to address 1>] <Street name> <House number>      #\r\n" + 
  "    # [<Addition to address 2>]                                             #\r\n" + 
  "    #########################################################################\r\n" + 
  "    (?:(?<BAdditiontoaddress1>.*?),\\s*(?=.*[,/]))?   # Addition to address 1\r\n" + 
  "    (?!\\s*No\\.)(?<BStreetname>\\S\\s*\\S(?:[^,\\#](?!\\b\\pN+\\s))*?(?<!\\s)) # Street name\r\n" + 
  "\\s*[/,]?\\s*(?:\\sNo\\.)?\\s+\r\n" + 
  "    (?<BHousenumber>\\pN+\\s*-?[a-zA-Z]?(?:\\s*[-/\\pP]?\\s*\\pN+(?:\\s*[-a-zA-Z])?)*|[IVXLCDM]+(?!.*\\b\\pN+\\b))(?<!\\s) # House number\r\n" + 
  "\\s*(?:(?:[,/]|(?=\\#)|\\s)\\s*(?!\\s*No\\.)\\s*\r\n" + 
  "    (?<BAdditiontoaddress2>(?!\\s).*?))? # Addition to address 2\r\n" + 
  ")\r\n" + 
  "\\s*\\Z";

// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.COMMENTS);
// Now create a matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("B_Street_name: " + m.group("BStreetname") );
    System.out.println("B_House_number: " + m.group("BHousenumber") );
    System.out.println("B_Addition_to_address_2: " + m.group("BAdditiontoaddress2") );
} else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/VINumW).

Output:

```
B_Street_name: Bygholm Søpark
B_House_number: 21B
B_Addition_to_address_2: null
```

Comment: Quick solution!!!. Thank you for helping me and a clear explanation for the solution. I tested it and it is working fine.

Comment: Hi Wiktor,  Now I have a requirement to use the same rex to be executed in C# however I am getting some regex syntax errors and I could not able to fix it. Could you please help me to change the syntax to run this REGEX in C# code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor for quick help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, what your problem might be, since your expression works fine. However, it seems you have many boundaries in your RegEx, which you may want to carefully DRY it with a large dataset samples.

If you wish to DRY that before you change it to c#, you may consider posting your question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex?sort=votes&pageSize=50), maybe someone would help you with that.

#### Test with (C#)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"\A\s*
(?: #########################################################################
    # Option A: [<Addition to address 1>] <House number> <Street name>      #
    # [<Addition to address 2>]                                             #
    #########################################################################
    (?:(?P<A_Addition_to_address_1>.*?),\s*)? # Addition to address 1
(?:No\.\s*)?
    (?P<A_House_number_1>\pN+[a-zA-Z]?(?:\s*[-\/\pP]\s*\pN+[a-zA-Z]?)*) # House number
\s*,?\s*
    (?P<A_Street_name_1>(?:[a-zA-Z]\s*|\pN\pL{2,}\s\pL)\S[^,#]*?(?<!\s)) # Street name
\s*(?:(?:[,\/]|(?=\#))\s*(?!\s*No\.)
    (?P<A_Addition_to_address_2>(?!\s).*?))? # Addition to address 2
|   #########################################################################
    # Option B: [<Addition to address 1>] <Street name> <House number>      #
    # [<Addition to address 2>]                                             #
    #########################################################################
    (?:(?P<B_Addition_to_address_1>.*?),\s*(?=.*[,\/]))? # Addition to address 1
    (?!\s*No\.)(?P<B_Street_name>\S\s*\S(?:[^,#](?!\b\pN+\s))*?(?<!\s)) # Street name
\s*[\/,]?\s*(?:\sNo\.)?\s+
    (?P<B_House_number>\pN+\s*-?[a-zA-Z]?(?:\s*[-\/\pP]?\s*\pN+(?:\s*[\-a-zA-Z])?)*|[IVXLCDM]+(?!.*\b\pN+\b))(?<!\s) # House number
\s*(?:(?:[,\/]|(?=\#)|\s)\s*(?!\s*No\.)\s*
    (?P<B_Addition_to_address_2>(?!\s).*?))? # Addition to address 2
)
\s*\Z";
        string input = @"Corso XXII Marzo 69";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;

        Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, options);
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}", m.Value, m.Index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Emma, Thank you for the sample code. I developed a java method by using the mentioned regex and elaborated the requirement in the question.